# Does the equation $3x^2-2y^2=1$ has infinitely many integer solutions such that $3|x$ ?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to show that the equation $3x^2-2y^2=1$ has infinitely many integer solutions such that $3|x$ ? ( If this can be shown then solutions of $12x^2-8y^2=4$ give infinitely many powerful numbers differing by $4$ )

Comment: What is a "powerful number"?

Comment: @GFauxPas : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number

Comment: Try looking up Pell's equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,y)$ is a solution, then so is $(5x+4y, 6x+5y)$.  Starting with $(1,1)$,
you get a sequence of solutions.  What is $x$ mod $3$ for these?

Comment: the $x$'s are not coming to be $0$ mod $3$ , if I assume $3|5x+4y$ , then $5(5x+4y)+4(6x+5y) \equiv x+y $ (mod $3$ ) .... what should I do then ?

Comment: Iterating the transformation mod $3$ I get $(1,1) \to (0,2) \to (2,1) \to (2,2) \to (0,1) \to \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way,
$$ 27 \cdot 3^2 - 2 \cdot 11^2 = 1.  $$
Given one $(x,y)$ pair with
$$ 27 x^2 - 2 y^2 = k,  $$ we get the next pair, of infinitely many, from
$$  (485x + 132 y, 1782x+485 y).  $$

With your $k=1$ you need start with the single seed pair $(3,11)$ to get all $(x,y)$ pairs with $x,y>0.$

For composite $k,$ you may need two or more seeds, but a small finite number in any case.

Comment: where did those $485 , 132  , 1782 $ come from ?